# Pandas: Call other function when crawling a DataFrame with a function

Tags: python, function, pandas

Using `Pandas`, I have this function which reads every row in a DataFrame and assigns the column value to a corresponding variable. Each pass in the function handles a row in the DataFrame and thus overwrites the variables.

I'm planning on adding more columns/variables and I find the coding to be quite inelegant because of the redundancy.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["Big red shirt", "Red", "L", "Shirt", "2016"], ["Medium black jeans", "Black", "M", "Pants", "2016"], ["Small blue shirt", "Blue", "S", "Shirt", "2016"]], columns=['Name', 'Color', 'Size', 'Category', 'Year'])

def crawl(assign):
    try:
        name = assign["Name"]
    except:
        name = None
    try:
        color = assign["Color"]
    except:
        color = None
    try:
        size = assign["Size"]
    except:
        size = None
    try:
        category = assign["Category"]
    except:
        category = None
    try:
        year = assign["Year"]
    except:
        year = None

df2[(["Name", "Color", "Size", "Category", "Year"])].apply(crawl, axis=1)
```

---

### Desired result

- I would instead like to use a briefer `function` which, according to the same principle above, takes each cell in the DataFrame from the columns and assigns it to corresponding variable (`name`, `color`, etc).
- If the corresponding cell in the DataFrame is empty, then the variable is set to `None`.

### My attempt

I started working on a solution which uses the below function – which is not tested! However, I'm unsure how to implement it in the main scheme of things since the function would have to call on `assign` in the original function `crawl`.

```
def get_cell(variables, *column_names):
    for var in variables:
        for col in list(column_names):
            try:
                var = assign[col]
            except:
                var = None
            finally:
                return var

get_cell(([name, color, size, category, year]), ["Name"], ["Color"], ["Size"], ["Category"], ["Year"])
```

---

### Sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Big red shirt", "Red", "L", "Shirt", "2016"], ["Medium black jeans", "Black", "M", "Pants", "2016"], ["Small blue shirt", "Blue", "S", "Shirt", "2016"]], columns=['Name', 'Color', 'Size', 'Category', 'Year'])
```

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
Name                    Color     Size     Category     Year
"Big red shirt"         "Red"     "L"      "Shirt"      "2016"
"Medium black jeans"    "Black"   "M"      "Pants"      "2016"
"Small blue shirt"      "Blue"    "S"      "Shirt"      "2016"
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you would provide a sample input data 5-7 rows for each: CSV file and `assign` DF and expected output. I'm 95% sure there is an easy and elegant way to achieve the same not using `crawl` and `get_cell` functions

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for your reply. I have edited the question and included sample data!

Comment: Is it a sample data for you CSV file or for the `assign` DF and where is the second one?

Comment: Or do you just want to put (assign) None/NaN to some cells using some (which one?) condition?

Comment: @MaxU: In reality I'm reading from a CSV, but I have edited the question so that it makes use of `df` and `df2`. The `crawl` function works row-by-row. If the value for column `"Name"` is `NaN`, in a certain row, I want to set the variable `Name = None`. Otherwise I want to set the variable to the string content of that cell. And so forth for the other columns/variables.

Comment: so you basically want to fill NaN's with None's - correct? did you check [fillna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function?

Comment: why would you want to fill NaN's with None's? I don't think it's a good idea

Comment: @MaxU Filling `NaN` with `None` is a secondary objective, the main objective is to devise a function that allows me to add many more columns with data without having to expand the main block in `crawl` with many rows that's essentially repeating the same idea. The reason for converting `NaN` to `None`   is simply because later parts of the script depend on `if x is not None` conditions to make other decisions.

Comment: It's still absolutely not clear to me what you want to achieve. Your `crawl()` function doesn't make much sense. I guess you should completely rewrite your question, provide a small sample of your CSV data in __text__ form (some creative SO members love to use pictures/screenshots for that) explain what do you want to do with this data and provide an expected output. The output will help us to understand your goals

Comment: And beside that take a closer look at the `na_values` parameter in `read_csv()` function